# Upgrading from makecert.exe to CertEnroll - issues with certificate trust

Tags: c#, ssl-certificate, x509certificate2, makecert, certenroll

I have an app that up until now used makecert.exe to generate self certificates. However as makecert does't have the ability to add a SubjectAltName field, I am needing to migrate the code to certenroll.dll

This is the original makecert code:

```
public static X509Certificate2 MakeCert(string subjectName)
    {
        X509Certificate2 cert;
        string certFile = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), subjectName + ".cer");

        var process = new Process
        {
            StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName = "makecert.exe",
                Arguments = " -pe -ss my -n \"CN=" + subjectName + ", O=myCert, OU=Created by me\" -sky exchange -in MyCustomRoot -is my -eku 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1 -cy end -a sha1 -m 132 -b 10/08/2018 " + certFile,
                UseShellExecute = false,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                CreateNoWindow = true
            }
        };

        process.Start();
        string str = "";
        while (!process.StandardOutput.EndOfStream)
        {
            var line = process.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
            str += line;
            //Console.WriteLine(line);
        }
        process.WaitForExit();

        cert = new X509Certificate2(certFile);
        // Install Cert
        try
        {

            var store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
            store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite);
            try
            {
                var contentType = X509Certificate2.GetCertContentType(certFile);
                var pfx = cert.Export(contentType);
                cert = new X509Certificate2(pfx, (string)null, X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet);
                store.Add(cert);
            }
            finally
            {
                store.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Could not create the certificate from file from {0}", certFile), ex);
        }
        return cert;
    }
```

And this is the certenroll.dll code:

```
   public static X509Certificate2 CertOpen(string subjectName)
    {
        try
        {
            X509Store store = new X509Store("My", StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
            store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
            try
            {
                var cer = store.Certificates.Find(
                    X509FindType.FindBySubjectName,
                    subjectName,
                    false);

                if (cer.Count > 0)
                {
                    return cer[0];
                }
                else
                {
                    return null;
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                store.Close();
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static X509Certificate2 CertCreateNew(string subjectName)
    {
        // create DN for subject and issuer
        var dn = new CX500DistinguishedName();
        dn.Encode("CN=" + subjectName, X500NameFlags.XCN_CERT_NAME_STR_NONE);


        // create a new private key for the certificate
        CX509PrivateKey privateKey = new CX509PrivateKey();
        privateKey.ProviderName = "Microsoft Base Cryptographic Provider v1.0";
        privateKey.MachineContext = false;
        privateKey.Length = 2048;
        privateKey.KeySpec = X509KeySpec.XCN_AT_SIGNATURE; // use is not limited
        privateKey.ExportPolicy = X509PrivateKeyExportFlags.XCN_NCRYPT_ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_EXPORT_FLAG;
        privateKey.Create();


        var hashobj = new CObjectId();
        hashobj.InitializeFromAlgorithmName(ObjectIdGroupId.XCN_CRYPT_HASH_ALG_OID_GROUP_ID,
            ObjectIdPublicKeyFlags.XCN_CRYPT_OID_INFO_PUBKEY_ANY,
            AlgorithmFlags.AlgorithmFlagsNone, "SHA256");

        // add extended key usage if you want - look at MSDN for a list of possible OIDs
        var oid = new CObjectId();
        oid.InitializeFromValue("1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1"); // SSL server
        var oidlist = new CObjectIds();
        oidlist.Add(oid);
        var eku = new CX509ExtensionEnhancedKeyUsage();
        eku.InitializeEncode(oidlist);

        // Create the self signing request
        var cert = new CX509CertificateRequestCertificate();

        cert.InitializeFromPrivateKey(X509CertificateEnrollmentContext.ContextUser, privateKey, "");

        X509Certificate2 signer = CertOpen("MyCustomRoot");
        if (signer == null)
        {
            throw new CryptographicException("Signer not found");
        }
        String base64str = Convert.ToBase64String(signer.RawData);


        ISignerCertificate signerCertificate = new CSignerCertificate();
        signerCertificate.Initialize(false, X509PrivateKeyVerify.VerifySilent, EncodingType.XCN_CRYPT_STRING_BASE64, base64str);
        // this line MUST be called AFTER IX509CertificateRequestCertificate.InitializeFromPrivateKey call,
        // otherwise you will get OLE_E_BLANK uninitialized object error.
        cert.SignerCertificate = (CSignerCertificate)signerCertificate;


        cert.Subject = dn;
        cert.Issuer.Encode(signer.Subject, X500NameFlags.XCN_CERT_NAME_STR_NONE); ; // the issuer and the subject are the same
        cert.NotBefore = DateTime.Now;
        // this cert expires immediately. Change to whatever makes sense for you
        cert.NotAfter = DateTime.Now.AddYears(10);
        cert.X509Extensions.Add((CX509Extension)eku); // add the EKU
        cert.HashAlgorithm = hashobj; // Specify the hashing algorithm
        cert.Encode(); // encode the certificate

        // Do the final enrollment process
        var enroll = new CX509Enrollment();
        enroll.InitializeFromRequest(cert); // load the certificate
        enroll.CertificateFriendlyName = subjectName; // Optional: add a friendly name

        string csr = enroll.CreateRequest(); // Output the request in base64
                                             // and install it back as the response
        enroll.InstallResponse(InstallResponseRestrictionFlags.AllowUntrustedCertificate,
            csr, EncodingType.XCN_CRYPT_STRING_BASE64, ""); // no password
                                                            // output a base64 encoded PKCS#12 so we can import it back to the .Net security classes
        var base64encoded = enroll.CreatePFX("", // no password, this is for internal consumption
            PFXExportOptions.PFXExportChainWithRoot);

        // instantiate the target class with the PKCS#12 data (and the empty password)
        return new System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2(
            System.Convert.FromBase64String(base64encoded), "",
            // mark the private key as exportable (this is usually what you want to do)
            System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable
        );
    }
```

Further to the assistance from Crypt32 I am now having issues with the signerCertificate.Initialize line. I can't seem to get it to use my self cert. root certificate. I assume that I'm trying to feed it in the wrong format as I am getting the following error:

> The certificate does not have the property that references a private
>   key. 0x8009200a (CRYPT_E_UNEXPECTED_MSG_TYPE)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify a signer certificate in `SignerCertificate` property of `IX509CertificateRequestCertificate` object (`cert` variable in your code). Signer certificate must be supplied in a form of `ISignerCertificate` instance. More information: [ISignerCertificate interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/certenroll/nn-certenroll-isignercertificate)

**Update 1 (13.12.2019)**

sorry to tell, but almost every piece in `ISignerCertificate` call is incorrect.

1. If you specify `X509PrivateKeyVerify.VerifyNone`, then private key existence is not checked. You need to use `X509PrivateKeyVerify.VerifySilent` flag.
2. You are using Base64 formatting with PEM header and footer to format certificate as a string. You are using `EncodingType.XCN_CRYPT_STRING_BASE64` which expects raw Base64 string without PEM envelope. PEM-formatted certificate uses `EncodingType.XCN_CRYPT_STRING_BASE64HEADER` encoding type. In your case I would do:

```
X509Certificate signer = CertOpen("MyCustomRoot");
if (signer == null) {
    throw new CryptographicException("Signer not found");
}
String base64str = Convert.ToBase64String(signer.RawData);
signerCertificate.Initialize(false, X509PrivateKeyVerify.VerifySilent, EncodingType.XCN_CRYPT_STRING_BASE64, base64str);

<...>
// put issuer directly from issuer cert:
issuer.Encode(signer.Subject, X500NameFlags.XCN_CERT_NAME_STR_NONE);
<...>
cert.InitializeFromPrivateKey(X509CertificateEnrollmentContext.ContextUser, privateKey, "");
// this line MUST be called AFTER IX509CertificateRequestCertificate.InitializeFromPrivateKey call,
// otherwise you will get OLE_E_BLANK uninitialized object error.
cert.SignerCertificate = signerCertificate;
```

Also, some minor improvements:

1. In `CertOpen` method you do not close the store.
2. `if (cer != null && cer.Count >0)` -- IIRC, `X509Certificate2Collection.Find` never returns null, so just check if returned collection is non-empty.
3. You are assigning ISignerCertificate object to request before initializing it. See my comments above.
4. Bear in mind, that `SHA512` is not enabled by default in all cryptographic modules. [SHA512 is disabled in Windows when you use TLS 1.2](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2973337/sha512-is-disabled-in-windows-when-you-use-tls-1-2)

**Update 2 (14.12.2019)**

I reproed the code with my modifications I provided yesterday, the code works. What `CRYPT_E_UNEXPECTED_MSG_TYPE` error suggests is that signer certificate doesn't have a private key in certificate store.

Comment: Thanks, I've added the following to the code:

            ISignerCertificate signerCertificate = new CSignerCertificate();
            signerCertificate.Initialize(false, X509PrivateKeyVerify.VerifyNone, EncodingType.XCN_CRYPT_STRING_HEX,??);
            cert.SignerCertificate = (CSignerCertificate)signerCertificate;

But I cannot work out what is required in place of ?? when the signerCertificate is initialized. Its asking for strCertificate. Is this the root certificate? If So, why does it need it when makecert doesn't, and does that mean I need to extract the root cert from the store

Comment: ISignerCertificate initializer expects either, certificate or thumbpring (if on Windows 7 or newer OS).

Comment: Thanks again. I tried to retrieve the root certificate using var cer = store.Certificates.Find(
                X509FindType.FindBySubjectName,
                "MyCustomRoot",
                false);

And fed it to the Initialize as a string, but it spits that back out. Is this the wrong way of doing it?

P.S Are you available for small projects? I could use someone that really knows encryption. Its largely beyond me.

Comment: Error is:The certificate does not have the property that references a private key. 0x8009200a (CRYPT_E_UNEXPECTED_MSG_TYPE)

Comment: ISignerCertificate signerCertificate = new CSignerCertificate();
            signerCertificate.Initialize(false, X509PrivateKeyVerify.VerifyNone, EncodingType.XCN_CRYPT_STRING_BASE64,ExportToPEM(CertOpen("MyCustomRoot")));


            cert.SignerCertificate = (CSignerCertificate)signerCertificate;


CertOpen() - uses X509Store.Certificates.Find to locate the root cert
ExportToPem() - returns the string root certificate with 'BEGIN/END CERTIFICATE' lines and uses (Convert.ToBase64String(cert.Export(X509ContentType.Cert), Base64FormattingOptions.InsertLineBreaks))

Comment: You'd better to update your initial question. Formatting in comments is terrible

Comment: Yeah sorry, I realized and updated original question

Comment: You are a star! I've made the code modifications you mentioned, but i'm, still getting CRYPT_E_UNEXPECTED_MSG_TYPE though. I also had to make a couple of small tweaks to your code to get it to compile: X509Certificate2 signer = CertOpen("MyCustomRoot"); and  cert.SignerCertificate = (CSignerCertificate)signerCertificate; I will update my original post again with the latest code

Comment: Original post updated with code. Its still throwing the same error sadly

Comment: at which line you get this exception?

Comment: Its at this line: signerCertificate.Initialize(false, X509PrivateKeyVerify.VerifySilent, EncodingType.XCN_CRYPT_STRING_BASE64, base64str); ---- I have just seen your reply about the private key. The root certificate MyCustomRoot was created with this makecert code: makecert.exe -r -ss my -n "CN=MyCustomRoot, O=myCert, OU=Created by me" -sky signature -eku 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1 -h 1 -cy authority -a sha1 -m 120 -b 09/05/2011 sig.cer ---------- and sig.cer was imported into the Current User->Personal->Certificates store. If I revert to using makecert for my certificates everything works as expected

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204249/discussion-between-james-and-crypt32).